# iPhone object not to be scrollable

Tags: iphone

I have UITableView that scroll as per expected.  I want the table to take up 80% of the space and I want another object at the top.  No biggie there.  My problem is that I don't want the object at the top to scroll when the table does.  Any help/examples of how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.  This is seen quite a bit with the search bar.  Thanks.

---

Ok, I got the concept, but now I am lacking the execution.  How can I go about adding code in my rootViewControler?  I tried the following and I see the two "headers" but they are still both scrolling.  I have added them to my viewDidLoad in my RootViewController

```
     UIView *containerViewA =
 [[[UIView alloc]
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)]
  autorelease];

 UIView *containerViewB =
 [[[UIView alloc]
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 60)]
  autorelease];

 UILabel *headerLabelA =
 [[[UILabel alloc]
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)]
  autorelease];

 UILabel *headerLabelB =
 [[[UILabel alloc]
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 40)]
  autorelease];

 headerLabelA.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 headerLabelA.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 headerLabelA.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
 headerLabelA.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
 headerLabelA.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 headerLabelA.text = NSLocalizedString(@"A", @"");

 headerLabelB.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 headerLabelB.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 headerLabelB.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
 headerLabelB.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
 headerLabelB.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 headerLabelB.text = NSLocalizedString(@"B", @"");


 [containerViewB  addSubview:headerLabelA];
 [containerViewA  addSubview:containerViewB];
 [self.view addSubview:containerViewA];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to arrange your view hierarchy so the other object is not in a scrollable view. So it should look like the following.

```
UIView
   |
   |-- UIView - this one won't scroll
   |
   |-- UIScrollView
            |
            |--UITableView
```

Comment: Gary,

I can see that this works in IB, but when I build, I don't see the items in the second UIView.  My apologies for the newb question.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know what's wrong if I can't see your IB project or code sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The Gary's answer is good already. I just want to elaborate it.

You have a UIViewControler A (that should not be a UITableVIewController or UIScrollViewController).

Then you have a UITableView B and UIView C.

You can do like this : `[A.view addSubview:C]` and then `[A.view addSubiew:B]`. Remember to init the view with the correct frame

Comment: Vodkhang,
I am a bit confused.  Your answer is different than Gary's.  Can you elaborate?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is similar, but different explanation, and I use code to do it. You still have the same hierarchy that the main view screen is a UIView, then you add another view A as subview of the main view in the top of the main view. Then you add another UITableView (or UIScrollView) below view A.